# using "Regarding" in the first of a sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Which ones are correct?
My English language teacher emphasises that the subject of the second part of the sentence here should be the one of the first part, so we should use "we" or "one" after "regarding X".

1. Regarding X, the trend is a slow rise and then a fall.
2. Regarding X, we can see that the trend is a slow rise and then a fall.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are fine.

In the first version, **regarding** need not be a conjugation of the verb *to regard* but a preposition. As per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regarding), it is equivalent to:

> **With respect to** X, the trend is a slow rise and then a fall.

Here, there is no "person" who is observing anything. The subject of the sentence is actually *the trend*.

Of course, if you *mean* to talk about people who are actually looking at X, then you do need to use the second sentence form.

Comment: How about "Turning to X". Are we required to write a person after the comma?

Comment: @mehrane If it's the trend that is doing the turning, then no. The trend is the subject. Subjects of sentences don't need to be *people*. In *the car turned left*, the car is the subject.

Comment: I mean exactly about my first question: Turning to the graph, (we can see that the trend is a slow rise and then a fall) or/( the trend is a slow rise and then fall). Base on your description, I suppose I should write: " Turning to the graph, we can see that the trend is a slow rise and then a fall"

Comment: @mehrane Your final sentence is correct.

Comment: Your description was clear and help me much. Thank you again.